# Renaming pandas column label based on location

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, rename

Let's say I have a dataframe and I want to rename the label for the third column. However, I don't know what the label name of the third column is currently, all I know is that it's the third column dataframe.

The examples I've seen for renaming df columns look something like this:

```
df.rename(columns={'Third_Col': 'New_Third_Col'}, inplace=True)
```

but I need something like

```
df.columns[3].name = "New_Third_Col'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use that as the key of the dictionary:

```
df.rename(columns={df.columns[3]: "New_Third_Col"}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: note this won't work as intended if two columns have the same name.